# How to calculate the height of a T-tree?

Tags: math, b-tree, avl-tree

I sit with a piece of code of a T-tree index. A T-tree is a modified AVL-tree so that each node can hold many elements, as opposed to the AVL-tree, that can hold only 2 elements per node. The balancing requirements are the same, ie, there can only be a height difference of 1 among all leaf nodes of the tree. In other words, a T-tree is 'well balanced'. Each node of a T-tree can at most have 2 children: left and right, just as the nodes of an AVL-tree.

As opposed to a B-tree which have index nodes and leaf nodes, whre only the leaf nodes hold elements, a T-tree carries elements(or pointers to elements) in all its nodes.

How do I correctly calculate the height of a T-tree if each node can hold 350 element pointers and I have populated it with 1 000 000 elements?

Comment: If it is well balanced, it is something similar to "adding the greatest value" or the smallest one and counting the levels

Comment: @thedarkside ofthemoon I want to be able to calculate the height of the tree without walking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the height, when knowing the number of elements? It should be something like

```
 boolean greater = true;
 int i = 0;
 while(greater)
 {
    if(tree.lenght() <= 2^i)
       greater = false;
    i = i+1;
 }
 height = i;
```

But only if it is perfectly balanced.

Comment: That doesn't take into account that I have 350 elements per node, right? It is not a binary tree. Would tree.lenght()/350 in your code do the trick?

Comment: Did I get it right? `T-tree is a binary tree that has more than one element per node. Ypu want to know the height=number of levels (not elements)`... Yes, mabe you should use `t.length()/350` if `t.length() = noOfElements` and just `t.length()` if it is equal to `noOfNodes`

Comment: Sorry for confusing you, I meant to say that a T-tree uses multi-value nodes. It's still binary of course.